# Pop from stack(LinkedList) using C# doesnt update Stack

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, stack

Hi I am using C# and trying to call a function Pop(Node class) from MainWindow. The pop method should return the poped value and remove it from the stack. The function is working and top value is removed from within the function, but in the MainWindow, the stack look same(LinkedList doesnt change). This is my Node class and Pop function.

```
public class Node
    {
        #region Constructor and Declarations
        public int custId;        
        public Node next;
        //other fields

 public Node(int _data, Node _next)
        {
            this.custId = _data;
            if (_next != null)
                this.next = _next;
            else
                this.next = null;
        }
        public Node()
        {
        }
        #endregion

//Make Stack
public Node MakeList()
        {

            Node slist1 = new Node(1, null);
            Node slist2 = new Node(2, null);
            Node slist3 = new Node(3, null);
            Node slist4 = new Node(4, null);
            Node slist5 = new Node(5, null);

            slist1.next = slist2;
            slist2.next = slist3;
            slist3.next = slist4;
            slist4.next = slist5;

            return slist1;
        }

#region PopCustomer
 public int pop(Node stacktop)
        {
            Node temp;
            int removedCustId = 0;
            if (stacktop == null)
                return -1;

            else
            {
                temp = stacktop;
                removedCustId = temp.custId;
                stacktop = temp.next;
                temp = null;
            }
            return removedCustId;
        }
#endregion
```

In the mainWindow I am creating the stack and calls the Pop. **BUT STACK LOOKS SAME - with CustIDs 1->2->3->4->5 NOT 2->3->4->5**

```
//MAIN WINDOW 
        #region MainWindow 
                    Node stackTop = new Node();
                    stackTop=stackTop.MakeList();
                    int popedItem = stackTop.pop(stackTop);//STACK LOOKS SAME - with CustIDs 1->2->3->4->5
                    #endregion
```

/

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

I think you main problem is with your approach for this problem. You are trying to code a stack in a C way and treating C# objects as C pointers.

In pop() function, the line **`temp = null;`** will only set variable **`temp`** as a **`null`** value, and **`stackTop`** will still have a non null value. You should know that setting variables as null is not the correct way to release an object.

In C# you are in safe mode by default and pointers are not allowed. I encourage you to read about [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28VS.80%29.aspx),  this is the common way to implement a data structure in C# and you will see examples using dynamic arrays.

Regards